# Determine physical file address of directory RVA in PE file

Tags: exe, binaryfiles, portable-executable, coff

How can I determine the image address (byte offset in file) of a particular data directory in a PE file?

For example, given data directories as follows:

```
directory  1  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory  2  RVA: 0xaf974  Size: 300
directory  3  RVA: 0xb8000  Size: 22328
directory  4  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory  5  RVA: 0xc0800  Size: 6440
directory  6  RVA: 0xbe000  Size: 27776
directory  7  RVA: 0x91760  Size: 28
directory  8  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory  9  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory 10  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory 11  RVA: 0xa46b8  Size: 64
directory 12  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory 13  RVA: 0x91000  Size: 1736
directory 14  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory 15  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
directory 16  RVA: 0x0  Size: 0
```

The import directory (#2 above) is shown as being at an RVA of 0xAF974. However, the import directory is NOT located at byte 0xAF974 of the EXE file. How do I compute the byte offset of the import directory in the file as it is written on the disk?

Comment: I posted some code, if you need more clarity, I'll be happy to try explaining it more. Even people who write PE code say the RVA stuff is a pain to understand, but once you have working code, the rest is easy:)

Answer (score 3):

This is fun! You have to loop through sections to find the correct location based on it's virtual address. Here is some code I wrote after a lot of

I can try to explain this, but it took a lot of time to understand it myself and I haven't looked at it in a few weeks and I already forgot a lot of the technical stuff. I was writing a C++ class to handle a lot of this too

In my code buffer is a pointer to a MapViewOfFile but it can be any char pointer.

```
/* Example usage...I know not perfect but should help a bit. */
    unsigned char * lpFile = (unsigned char *)(void *)MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0,0, 0);

    if(lpFile==NULL) {
        printf("Failed to MapViewOfFile\r\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    header_dos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFile;
    header_nt = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)&lpFile [header_dos->e_lfanew];

    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY import = header_nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR im = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)&lpFile[RVA2Offset(lpFile, import.VirtualAddress)];


        /* RVA is relative to the section it resides in. */
    int RVA2Offset(unsigned char * buffer, DWORD rva)
    {
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS header = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) &buffer[ ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer)->e_lfanew ];
        PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER section = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) &buffer[ ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer)->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ];

        for(int sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < header->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; sectionIndex++) {
            /*
                Check if the RVA is within the virtual addressing space of the section
                Make sure the RVA is less than  the VirtualAddress plus its raw data size
                IMAGE_HEADER_SECTION.VirtualAddress = The address of the first byte of the section when loaded into memory, relative to the image base. For object files, this is the address of the first byte before relocation is applied.
                Our ImageBase is 0, since we aren't loaded into actual memory
            */
            section = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) &buffer[ ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer)->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + (sectionIndex*sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER))];

            if (rva >= section->VirtualAddress && (rva <= section->VirtualAddress + section->SizeOfRawData)) {
                /**
                    PointerToRawData gives us the section's location within the file.
                    RVA - VirtualAddress = Offset WITHIN the address space
                **/
                return section->PointerToRawData + (rva - section->VirtualAddress);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I kind of suspected something like this was necessary. I will try this and post an update.

Comment: If you need any guidance just ask:P